# SQL select rows in a given Order

Tags: sql, select

I have a table that i wish to select rows from, 
I want to be able to define the order in which the results are defined.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY (CSV of Primary key)
```

EG:

```
Select * 
from table 
order by id   (3,5,8,9,3,5)
```

Wanted results

```
ID | * |
-----------
3 ....
4 ....
```

etc

I'm guessing this isn't possible?

Comment: Why would you have `4` in the example output?

Comment: When asking for help with SQL, always mention what DBMS (MySQL, Postgres, etc) and version you are using, as features vary wildly. If you're looking for a portable solution (which is not necessarily the same as a standards-compliant solution), then mention that explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `field()` function in MySQL:

```
order by field(id, 3, 5, 8, 9, 3, 5)
```

Of course, `3` and `5` match the the first time, not the second, so they are superfluous.

You can use a similar function `choose()` in SQL Server.  Or, use `case` in any database:

```
order by (case when id = 3 then 1
               when id = 5 then 2
               when id = 8 then 3
               when id = 9 then 4
          end);
```

Comment: Thanks, Can i just confirm I could do order by field(id, $string) Where the string would contain a CSV. 

Thanks again

Comment: @RossW . . . No.  If you are using MySQL, you would use `find_in_set()` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you could do something like this:

```
Select * 
from table 
order by CASE id  WHEN 3 THEN 1 WHEN 5 THEN 2 WHEN 8 THEN 3 WHEN 9 THEN 4 WHEN 3 THEN 5 WHEN 5 THEN 6 ELSE 10000 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a CASE expression in the ORDER BY clause
SELECT * FROM something

ORDER BY
CASE #something
 WHEN 'this' THEN 1

Answer (score 0):

For a short list of values, it's possible to generate a CASE statement which prioritises the options. For instance,  to order by id in sequence (3,5,8,9):

```
ORDER BY CASE id
    WHEN 3 THEN 0
    WHEN 5 THEN 1
    WHEN 8 THEN 2
    WHEN 9 THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END ASC
```

This obviously doesn't scale that well for longer lists, and in your example you have duplicate items (not sure if that was deliberate) which requires you to select the same row twice in different points in the sequence.

A more complex solution is to create a table of (id, sequence_position) pairs, and JOIN that to the rest of your query. A normal INNER JOIN would also filter by those rows; if that wasn't what was wanted, you could use LEFT JOIN and COALESCE(sequence_position, $num_items+1) to give the same as the ELSE clause in the CASE version.

You don't mention what DBMS (MySQL, Postgres, etc) and version you're running, so I can't say exactly what your options for that are, but they include things like temporary tables, and CTEs (WITH statements) or sub-queries involving VALUES clauses or UNION ALL statements.

Note that one way or another you're probably looking at dynamically generating SQL here, not just using a comma-separated string directly. It's possible that you could make a custom function to generate that SQL directly, or even that your DBMS has set-based functions that would help, but again I don't know what you're using.